# Wrong exit code of a Windows process (C#/C++/etc.)?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

Our C# application exits with code 0, even though it is explicitly returning -1 in the code:

```
internal class Program
{
    public int Main()
    {
        ....
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The same happened if `void Main` was used:

```
internal class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        ....
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
}
```

As other questions on SO suggested it could have been an unhandled CLR/C++/native exception in some other thread.
However I've added graceful shutdown of all managed/native threads right before this the last one, but the behavior stayed.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this happened because we used [JobObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make sure that all child process exit when current process exits using this code in C (we actually p-invoked from C#):

```
HANDLE h = ::CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL);

JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION info;
::ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));
info.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
::SetInformationJobObject(h, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, &info, sizeof(info));
::AssignProcessToJobObject(h, ::GetCurrentProcess());

...

::CloseHandle(h);

return -1;
```

This code adds the current process and all its child processes to a job object which will be closed on current process exit.
BUT it has a side-effect when `CloseHandle` was invoked it would kill the current process without ever reaching to the line `return -1`. And since `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` flag automatically kills all processes there is no way to set a exit code for all processes, so OS exited the process with exit code 0.

In C# we followed standard guidelines to clean-up resources and used `SafeHandle`-derived class to make sure that `CloseHandle` is invoked and absolutely the same happened - before CLR actually exited it invoked `::CloseHandle` for all `SafeHandle`s ignoring the actual return code set both by return value and `Environment.Exit`.

However what's even more interesting, is that if an explicit (or not so explicit) call to `CloseHandle` is removed in both C# and C++, OS will still close all the handles at the process exit after CLR/CRT exited, and the actual exit code will be returned. So sometimes it is good not to clean-up resources :-) or in another words, until a native `::ExitProcess` is invoked, you can't guarantee that the exit code will be intact.

So to fix this particular issue I could either call `AssignProcessToJobObject` whenever a child process is started or removed the explicit (or not so explicit) call to `CloseHandle`. I chose the first approach.